# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling new entity() method in iOS 10 / macOS Sierra Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

The new `entity()` method helps us avoid magic strings. Rather than saying something like `managedObjectModel.entitiesByName["foo"]`, we can say `Foo.entity()`.

The problem is that in my testing it always throws `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I've configured my `NSPersistentStore` and I've run a test query to make sure that everything is set up properly.

Any insight? What are the prerequisites to call this method?

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your setup.

To check, open Xcode, start a new project, choose "Master/Detail", check "Core Data". In the `MasterViewController`, insert this line anywhere:

```
print("The entity is ", Event.entity(), ".")
```

You will see that it works out of the box. Notice that in the model editor, when inspecting the `Event` entity, the option "Codegen" is set to "Class Definition".

Comment: Turns out there was nothing wrong with my setup. My answer sums up the difficulty I was having and how to resolve it, though it smells like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that merely initializing `NSPersistentStore` and calling `loadPersistentStores` isn't enough. You have to explicitly or implicitly use its `managedObjectModel` property at least once, most likely due to lazy loading.

I tentatively regard this as a bug. The `entity()` method should probably do this itself under the hood, though there may be other considerations.

Comment: Interesting. Given how Core Data has worked in the past, this isn't entirely surprising. But this new method should either (a) just work via some other change or (b) give a meaningful error message if (a) is impossible. I consider it a bug as well.